# FullCalendar associate people with an event

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have just started using FullCalendar (still testing it), specifically version 5, and I would like to associate people with an event. For instance "Meeting 1" has "Person 1, Person 2" and "Meeting 2" has "Person 3, Person 2" attending. I would like to be able to click on a meeting and see the attendees; update (add/delete) the attendees.

I think this is best done by treating people as resources. Is that correct or is there a better way to do this?

Is there a good example of this available somewhere please?

Comment: You can use resources if you want, but it changes the way the calendar is displayed, too (e.g. see examples of the timeline view or resource timegrid). Or you can just add the person's information as extended properties of the event object, and then write some code in the eventDidMount callback to modify the event's display so it will show it on the screen (or cause it to be displayed in a tooltip/popup when the event is clicked/hovered/whatever you want).

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your reply. I have looked at these (timeline view and resource timegrid). and they do not do what I want. With the timeline the resources are at the left of the page and do not change as you select each event. What I want is to select the event and then show the associated people. I suppose I will need to use the click event, do a call to the database to get the people and then display them in a modal. I was hoping there would be a more efficient way.

Comment: `use the click event, do a call to the database`...you don't need to do a separate call to the database. Like I said, if you put the list of associated people into the extended properties of each event when you first provide the event data to the calendar, you can then simply organise it so that data is displayed in a little popup whenever you hover over the event or click on it - fullCalendar's callbacks will give you access to the event's properties so you can retrieve them on-demand without needing to go back to the database.